# Storing a video in phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database to display video content. I tried storing the video clips in my database as a longblob but the file size is too large. My video clips are recorded in HD which was necessary to have a clear picture.

I tried to store the file path as a varchar in my database, although I'm not sure if I am doing it right. I am storing the location of the video on my computer.

One of my file paths is as follows: C:/wamp/www/com904/eNISAT/Password/Change Password Tutorial.wmv.

I tried to select all from my table to display the videos on my php page displayVideos.php but I get my file path output in text within my html table.

Here is the code in my displayVideos.php file.

```
<?php

require_once("db_connection.php");


//Start session
/*
Sessions is a mechanism to preserve data across subsequent accesses. Using   sessions, a website is able to maintain state, that is, 
remember which requests they received previously. Without sessions, websites would not have progressed beyond simple static HTML pages.
*/
session_start();

//Select database
$database = "com904";
$db = mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

include_once 'db_connection.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="sky blue">
<center>
<div id="header">
<h1> Click on each video to view your tutorials <h1/>
</div>
<div id="body">
<table width="80%" border="1"bgcolor = "white">

<tr>
<th colspan="4">Your eNISAT Tutorials
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Support Question</td>
<td>Video</td>
</tr>
<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM enisatquestion";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
{
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['eNISATQuestion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['eNISATVideo'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
 }
 ?>
 </table>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It should be `localhost/com904/eNISAT/Password/Change Password Tutorial.wmv` or `127.0.0.1t/com904/eNISAT/Password/Change Password Tutorial.wmv`

Comment: 1. there is no such thing as a "phpmyadmin database"

Comment: How do you show a video on a web page? Using proper html tags. So wrap the path in those proper tags and youre good. Just displaying the path doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly want to actually store the relative URL in the database (`com904/eNISAT/Password/Change Password Tutorial.wmv`) rather than the absolute URL, and definitely not the path *on disk* as you've done. Even if you make the decision to show an absolute URL you can do that through your PHP code rather than storing the hostname in the database.

Once you've adjusted the path you store, you need to adjust the display of the output. It's amazing that none of the tutorials dealt with this. Instead of printing the URL, try printing an `href` with the URL as the link destination. You can make the link text whatever you want; maybe extracting only the filename or by pulling from a `title` field in the database.

Additionally, you should URL escape the result before inserting it in to the database. PHP provides several functions that can do this (each has a particular variation from the others, so you should evaluate each before you decide).